# Python embedded in website

Tags: python, python-2.7, ide

I am making a tutorial site for Python ([here](http://learnpython.dx.am)), and I want to have an embedded Python try it panel like this (http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp):

[image: Example (http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)]

I tried [Trinket](https://trinket.io/), but I don't like how it saved when you modify it and how it is a little too advanced. I want a more simple editor like W3Schools has (image above), but for Python. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For running Python code in the browser, I would say [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) or [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/):

If you just need an editor then there is [CodeMirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeMirror).

Answer (score -1):

You can try using this:

https://repl.it/languages/python3

They have an online editor you can play with and show you results right on the right panel.

If you ever need to find an easy way to learn a programming language you can always search for "Fiddles" online and a lot of editors will show up.